# How to calculate ray unit grid intersections?

Tags: raycasting, voxels, octree

[image]

*P* is ray origin, *D* direction. How do I calculate *tx, ty*(s)? This is for octree raycast. The primary goal is to get 1st intersection voxel (v) then second (v") and so on.

Comment: See answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40767/fast-3d-point-cuboid-volume-intersection-test/40771#40771). Closing as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fast 3d point -> cuboid volume intersection test](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40767/fast-3d-point-cuboid-volume-intersection-test)

Comment: @Engineer the answer points to a book and dead link for source code. Not really an answer.

Comment: Not a full answer either, but this video might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbSee-XM7WA

Comment: [This is probably the algorithm being referred to elsewhere](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf).

Comment: I tried to take a different approach to explaining this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67181559/402022), perhaps that helps.

Comment: All examples start inside of grid. What if origin is outside?

Comment: Either extend / redefine your grid to include the origin or find where the ray first intersects the grid & use that as your starting point.

Comment: Yes find where first intersects, but how? AABB test?

Comment: You can check for intersections against the four bounding segments of the grid (i.e. the bounding rectangle (xMin, yMin) (xMax, yMax)) By definition the XY axis grid is already axis aligned.