# Java2D Collision Detection

Tags: java, collision-detection, slick

I've been wrapping my head around Java2D collision detection. I am working with Slick library and trying to figure a simple clean code to check if a collision has occurred.

The idea is fairly simple, I have an Entity class seen as a bound box (a rectangle in my case,but I am not using the intersects method), I am trying to run a check if current entity is colliding with any other entities passed in an arraylist:

```
    public boolean collides(Object o){
    Entity e = (Entity) o;
    return x + width > e.x && x < e.x + e.width && y + height > e.y && y < e.y + e.height;
}

public boolean collisidesAny(ArrayList al){
    for(Object o: al){
        return collides(o);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now the thing with this code is that it gives me quite a bit of headache. The second method will return true the moment the objects do collide, and if I was to use it with a keyboard I wouldn't be able to move back since it won't allow any commands. 
Naturally I tried with sending the entity one step back when collision does occur, but the problem is I can't know where did it occur from, so I would have to do a step back both x and y wise. Other way I tried was a priori check, where I would check if a collision would occur if a step was made and if it wasn't I would allow the step, but this has gotten really complicated and buggy very quickly. 
Therefor I would like to know if there was a way to do collision this way?

Thanks for taking your time to read this,
P.

Comment: I suggest searching the site for collision detection. There are many dozens of questions about how to implement collision detection.

Comment: I did do that, haven't found anything related to my case.

Comment: There really are a flood of different discussions on collision-handling.  It's one of the more popular topics around here.  Incidentally, what you're describing is really collision-HANDLING, not collision detection, if that helps you find your solution.

Comment: I suppose I will look for that then, if I manage to find an answer I will gladly delete this post :)

Comment: i have some code here that may be useful: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25818/how-to-implement-a-2d-collision-detection-for-android/40235#40235

Comment: From a general programming perspective, you should be using ['Generics'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) if at all possible; among other things, it'd make it so you don't have to (explicitly) cast types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some great resources within the StackExchange Community on collision handling:

- [How did LoZ: A Link to the Past handle sub-tile collisions?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8336/how-was-collision-detection-handled-in-the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-to-the-past)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling
- [2D Platformer AABB collision problems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/2d-platformer-aabb-collision-problems)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-collision-detection
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981866/quadtree-for-2d-collision-detection

And here are some outside stackexchange:

- http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/2D-Polygon-Collision-Detection

Comment: You can just post a comment that says "search the site" or "google it"

Comment: Wow, downvoting for providing it, though?

Comment: I just commented, not down voted, sorry.

Comment: No worries, Byte.